# Cakephp 3 : Time formating HTML helper not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have tried to change Time format like this below code

```
<?php echo $this->Time->format($news->created,'%B %e, %Y'); ?>
```

My desire output like `August 22, 2011`. But I found the output only `%`.

I have also used namespace `use Cake\View\Helper\TimeHelper;`

Answer (score 1):

Cake 3.x returns an instance of `Cake\I18n\Time` from datetime and timestamp fields. You can simply do:

```
// Using PHPs DateTime format string
<?= $news->created->format('F d, Y') ?>

// Using ICU date formatting string
<?= $news->created->i18nFormat('MMMM d, Y') ?>
```

Note that `TimeHelper::format()` is just a shortcut for `Time::i18nFormat()`

```
<?= $this->Time->format($news->created, 'MMMM d, Y') ?>
```

1. [PHP format parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
2. [ICU data/time format parameters](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

May I know if this format is what you want?

`<?php echo $news->created->format('F d, Y'); ?>`

I don't know if you want the % or not, but it also works if you put the % sign in.

By the way for your `'%B %e, %Y'`, I get %439 %Asia/Hong_Kong, %2011.

---

Reference: [PHP: Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) , [CakePHP Time Formatting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake%5CI18n%5CTime::setToJSONFormat)

Comment: I actually apply this doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::format

For get output like August 22, 2011

Comment: Oh, I always skip referencing 2.x as it seems as quite large difference with 3.x and I started learning CakePHP　from 3.x. Is this in your view? I have edited the answer for another try.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $this->Time->format($news->created,'%B %e, %Y');
```

Your code is right but date format of $news->created should be in Y-m-d or Y-M-d

Comment: Here time format is default cakephp time format, like that 2013-03-12 04:18:25

Comment: Actually the code isn't correct, the format is wrong for CakePHP 3.x

Answer (score -1):

```
   echo $this->Time->format( 'F jS, Y h:i A',  $post['Post']['created'], null,  $user['User']['time_zone']);

//  Will display August 22nd, 2011 11:53 PM for a user in GMT+0
```

// August 22nd, 2011 03:53 PM for a user in GMT-8
// and August 23rd, 2011 09:53 AM GMT+10;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html

Comment: The question is about CakePHP 3.x